# Space between inline block elements

Tags: html, css

Is there a space by default for inline block elements? i think there's both `margin-left` and `margin-bottom` set to `-4px` (on chrome, margin-bottom is -5px). why would they want to do that? i mean because of this, while setting `margin-top` for the container of all these `inline-block` elements (each were 25%), the third element is ending up on the next line. why does this happen?

Comment: i have like 75+ lines of code for html, mate.:-(

Comment: add it and make a fiddle.

Comment: Inline block elements are treated like words in a sentence so if you have spaces between them in your code (ie for indentation) then you will get spaces between them on the screen.  Either delete the space or comment it out

Comment: does that mean breaking space will end up -4px margin as well?

Comment: Depends on your font size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two common ways to avoid the space:

1. You can shift the tags up to avoid line breaks between elements:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
    one</li><li>
    two</li><li>
    three</li>
</ul>
```

2. Or you can comment out the line break:

```html
<ul>
    <li>one</li><!--
    --><li>two</li><!--
    --><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

---

You get the space because there *is* some space between the elements (tabs and line breaks count as "spaces" ). By getting rid of the spaces between the elements, you'll fix the problem. :)

Comment: here's some repuations for u.:-)

Answer (score 2):

Just comment the spaces and line breaks between the elements to avoid the unwanted margin:

```
<div class="inline-block-element></div><!--

--><div class="inline-block-element></div>
```

Comment: i tried margin-left: -4px. it worked. but why would adding margin/padding top affect the structure of the elements?

Comment: You should thing about inline-blocks elements as single words. The only difference is that they also are tags, which means they can be styled, allowing them to have a margin that actually moves them around. You could add margin to a single word, if there is a way to target only that word in the css.